# Could a semi-permeable membrane, which releases CO2 but contains O2 and nitrogen, biologically exist?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, xenobiology

I'm trying to create an alien which has external lungs. Air can be inhaled normally however, is it plausible that the material the lungs are made of is semi-permeable. Containing the nitrogen and oxygen while allowing the carbon dioxide to diffuse outward?

Since nitrogen and oxygen are smaller than CO2, would it be possible for them to diffuse through a membrane into second chamber while the CO2 remains in the original?

Comment: I'll let a chemist sort that out for you properly, but CO2 is going to be the larger of those molecules. I don't think any kind of passive filter is going to work the way you want.

Comment: @SeanBoddy That's a great point! Would it be possible that the air was pressurized within the lung, causing the o2 to pass through a membrane into a seperate chamber while the co2 stays stored in the first, subsequently being disposed of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it an *active* process.  It's not just holes of the right size, but rather ports like found in cells.  An enzyme-like molecule picks up CO₂ and then the complex is taken into the membrane, and eventually presented to the other surface with a molecule that will let go when it's in position.  You can find inspiration from various real biochemical systems.

I assume you want it to be different from the way our lungs work. For comparison, both gases cross the membrane freely in either direction, so with a normal fluid on each side would simply maintain equilibrium.  But the blood doesn't carry the gases in solution; rather, the red blood corpuscles act in a [non-linear manner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemoglobin#Cooperativity).

So simplest case is to have your alien membrane be layered with something like our Hemoglobin in the middle.  Ours are made to cycle by moving them in and out of the [areloi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulmonary_alveolus%20alveoli).  I was thinking it could be done in the alien by bucket brigade of different molecules, which consume power to do their work.

Comment: It wouldn't be an "enzyme-like molecule", it would be an enzyme. In fact, there is an enzyme that already does this or something similar. It turns CO2 into bicarbonate for transport in the blood an/or converts bicarbonate into CO2 in the lungs to be exhaled. Nature got there first.

Comment: @a4android I mean rather than causing a reaction to take place that would be possible without the enzyme (though slow or energetically unfavorable) it would carry it to another place and leave it unchanged.  The “let go” signal is not a binding of reactants, but something about the conditions outside vs inside.

Comment: Maybe so, but there's already a mechanism that does this, and it's an enzyme.

Answer (score 2):

Two things to keep in mind.

First, many animals like frogs and worms [can breath through their skins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutaneous_respiration)
 (notice the frogs also have lungs, but can live without them). This might render external lungs redundant, depending on the oxygen needs of your creature.

Second, if you creature has lungs because it needs a large oxygen intake and cutaneous breathing will not do. Some eggheads developed [amide filters that can separate carbon dioxide with great efficiency, and nitrogen with less efficiency but still in considerable amounts from a medium](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S003238611201052X). Your creature might develop something through natural selection, and it might be more or less efficient for each gas as you see fit for your story. The captured gases can then be taken to another part of the body and expelled.

Or it might just ventilate the lungs like we do, by pumping air into them. Would be less efficient than a polyamide filter, but would be more natural and require less suspension of disbelief.